# i need to access a POST request Response and that Response is An array of SearchSample objects Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, nyckel

The Function in my Component :

```
searchWithNyckel(){

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', this.updateFormGroup.get('updateProduct.image').value);

this.productService.searchProductNyckel(formData).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.resForSearch= data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.resForSearch));
    // this.resForSearch.values()
  }
)
}
```

The Function in my service :

```
searchProductNyckel(formData: FormData):Observable<SearchRes[]> {
    const url = `https://www.nyckel.com/v0.9/functions/1wx5f2474e1ntc/search`
    return this.httpClient.post<SearchRes[]>(url,formData);
  }
```

The Console Response :

```
{
"searchSamples": 
    [{
        "sampleId": "<sampleId>",
        "distance": 0.86,
        "externalId": "<externalId>"
    }]
}
```

I NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF sampleId and distance

Answer (score 1):

You can access the content of the response by using a map operator.

for instance:

```
this.productService.searchProductNyckel(formData).pipe(
   map (response => response.searchSamples)
).subscribe((samples => console.log(sample))
```

will output the array of samples.

If you just want to access 1 variable of the 1st item of the array, you can use:

```
this.productService.searchProductNyckel(formData).pipe(
   map (response => response.searchSamples[0].sampleId)
).subscribe((id => console.log(id))
```